# Duplicacy on 2 fields

Tags: workflow

[image: Workflow]

I know I'm not the first person to ask this but I've read many blogs, none of them solved my problem. I have a custom object say "Invitation__c" where I have a custom Date field.

My requirement is I want the combination of Name and Date field to be unique. I already created a Unique Case Insensitive Text field (Composite_Key__c) and a Workflow rule (Everytime a record is created and edited) with Rule criteria `Invitation: Composite Key EQUALS Invitation: Name & Date` and a Field Update Workflow on Composite Key field.  But its not solving my problem. Its only giving the error on Duplicate Name but not on the combination of Name and Date.

I guess the Workflow rule needs to be updated but I've tried many options, none solved it.Please help.

Answer (score 0):

First of all -

the workflow criteria should be such that it fires every time. Something like :

**Name** is not '' (Blank)

Next the field update formula value should be like

**Name & '-' & TEXT(MyDateField__c)**

this should work

Please ensure - 
1. its a date field and not datetime 
2. Keep only name criteria in W/F rule. Remove the other one.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. I edited the workflow as suggested:                     Rule criteria- (Invitation: Name NOT EQUAL TO null) AND (Invitation: Date NOT EQUAL TO null). Field update field:                                                    Field to Update- Invitation: Composite Key. Formula Value Name & "-" & TEXT(Date__c).                                                                                                            But this is not solving the issue either. Please suggest.

Comment: Does it work now?

Comment: Nope. :( Please refer my previous comment and suggest if I'm heading towards the right approach.

Comment: Check updates to answer

Comment: I edited the rule. But still it is allowing me to create a duplicate record. Please note that at the toke of creating the record, I'm only entering data in Name and Date__c field and not in Composite key field as I only need the unique record against the combination of Name and Date__c field.

Comment: Kindly create 3 to 4 records that you feel are duplicate but donot give errors. Add composite field to page layout and see what value its showing over there.

Comment: I've created 4 records with duplicate combination and none gave the error. Since Composite is a Text(100) (External ID) (Unique Case Insensitive)  type, it is not showing any value in all 4 records.

Comment: Can you include screenshot of your W/F rule and field update in the Question?

Comment: Apologies for the delay. I've added the image with question. Please suggest.